# What is the gdb command equivalent of bp MODULE_NAME+0x12345678 in WinDBG?

Tags: debugging, gdb, windbg

What is the gdb command equivalent of `bp MODULE_NAME+0x12345678` in WinDBG?

I found this command useful to debug with ASLR (w/o disabling it).

Answer (score 0):

Reading through the man page shows the command `break [file:][function|line]`

More specifically you would load the file into gdb as normal, and then enter `break function_name+offset_value` such as: `break main+12345678`